# Would an opening to the outside help me dry out a basement?

Tags: basement, ventilation, moisture

I had a hot tub problem which resulted in huge amounts of water gushing out into the yard.  This happened a couple of times.  (Hot tub repair company from hell.)  The hot tub is situated a few feet from the house.  The ground is still saturated like a dripping sponge.  As a result the walls and floor or the unfinished cellar, which does have a functioning sump pump, has not dried out yet, several months later.  I have tried running a dehumidifier, a fan and a space heater in the cellar, but that hasn't helped a whole lot.  I suspect it's because there is no window I can open down there.  Would it help to create a small temporary opening to the outside?  Which I would close up once I've accomplished the mission.

Answer (score 2):

The floor and walls will not dry out until the ground outside absorbs the water. I would avoid making an opening in a perfectly good wall. Once the outside ground water is gone, you should start to see some improvement.
Is it possible to dig a hole where the water is bad and pump the water to a different spot far away from you house?? Just a thought.

Comment: Maybe I exaggerated.  If I dig a hole I don't think it will not fill with standing water like when you're making sand castles at the beach.  It's a slow seeping.

Comment: You don't think it will not fill means it will fill...

Comment: It doesn't feel soggy to walk on.  But I do see that the sump pump is still getting triggered a few times a day, even when there has been no rain for four days.  And the floor and walls just haven't dried out in these several months, whereas they used to dry out within a couple weeks of a big rainfall, no matter how massive the amount of precipitation that fell was.  I'm confused.

Comment: Have you had a lot of rain since the hot tub issue?  The fact that the sump is running means there's still water sinking into the ground. I think you're just going to have to wait it out.

Comment: I guess it's been a less dry summer than last year.  Are you saying there's no point in making one or two temporary openings and running the fan and dehumidifier?  The water only sheets across the floor after a severe downpour.  That only happens once in a while.

Comment: Define temporary opening. Where would you make it?  If you have no windows what are you going to do?, knock a hole in the concrete walls, cut a hole in the ceiling,(floor above)?  Run the dehumidifier...

Comment: There is a row of concrete blocks which are set close with no mortar.  I was thinking maybe we could knock one of those out.  I wanted to first decide whether to create an opening, and then if yes, consult with a handyman I know who knows my house pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Air flow certainly can help, especially if the relative humidity is low. You would be better off with two windows open and staging 2 floor sized fans at the basement windows *outside the house* with one pulling air out, and the other pulling the air in.

This by no means is a "quick cure", but it's yet something that would have some positive effect on your issue.

You'd be doing this for days, btw.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I might have a window fan somewhere which has two fans next to each other.  They can be set up for one to exhaust and the other to bring in.  I suppose having a cross breeze would be helpful.